Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version. ERR : flutterfire_cli as globally activated doesn't support Dart 3.4.3. What should do
Just tried to run my app where received an blue error in Debug console:

Unhandled Exception: [core/duplicate-app] A Firebase App named
"[DEFAULT]" already exists.

Decided to delete: ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist (running on IOS).
After that tried to:

dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

Next to:

flutterfire configure --project=

After that i received yellow error:

Xcode build done.                                           22.4s
Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build: ↳
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations: 2
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:4E8318E4-AE74-4AA9-AD3A-7ADFE0D2291E, OS:18.0, name:iPhone 16 Pro }
** BUILD FAILED ** 2
Xcode's output: ↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/zg/x_4x6l1s34s2bsqj1xkp40rw0000gn/T/flutter_tools.9QXPs7/flutter_ios_build_temp_diratu3Iw/temporary_xcresult_bundle
2
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++'
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++', '-lsqlite3', '-lz'
Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version.
FINE: Pub 3.4.3
ERR : flutterfire_cli as globally activated doesn't support Dart 3.4.3.
|
| try:
| dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli to reactivate
FINE: Exception type: DataException
FINE: package:pub/src/utils.dart 583:36                                dataError
| package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 412:9                       GlobalPackages.find.
| dart:collection                                                  _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach
| package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 403:29                      GlobalPackages.find

Tried to:

activate/deactivate flutterfire_cli
clean xcode project build cache
reinstalled pods
added "export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"" inside the ~/.bash_profile
copied "GoogleService-Info.plist" from firebase console and pasted it to ios/Runner folder.

flutter --version says:
Flutter 3.24.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 603104015d (13 days ago) • 2024-10-24 08:01:25 -0700
Engine • revision db49896cf2
Tools • Dart 3.5.4 • DevTools 2.37.3
flutter doctor says Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.4, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64, locale en-PL)
Also, tried to add 'name' (project name) property inside the

await Firebase.initializeApp()

inside the main()
Guys, do you have any clue what is happening?
